# How to disable windows news feed beside searchbar?

Tags: windows, searchbar

The following opens up when i click on the search icon on windows:

[search bar in windows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DbzE4.png)

On the right side you can see some news/ some stuff, windows thinks might be interesting for me.

My problem is, that i alwas get distrackted by these news and pictures and stuff like that. I really want to deactivate those reccomendations, but i dont know how.

does anyone know how to disable this news stuff there?

I tryed to go to settings but i didnt found much for this news feed thing. the only stuff i found was for the search results, but that is not what is interesting for me. i really just want to deactivate the news feed stuff.

Comment: Use Group Policy

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here are three ways to do that:

1. Right click on the Taskbar - Search - and then uncheck Search Highlights
2. Group Policy:
   Computer Configuration > Administrative Templates > Windows Components > Search > Allow search highlights  --> Disable it
3. Registry:
   Navigate to `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\Windows Search` and look for the `EnableDynamicContentInWSB` entry. If there is no one, please create one. Right click on the empty space - New - DWORD (32-bit) and name it: `EnableDynamicContentInWSB`.
   The Value should be changed to 0.

---

Screenshot of using Taskbar (Option 1. above)

[image]

Comment: No Problem, you are always welcome.

Comment: und danke vielmals :D